# Tkinter updating label fails with "AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'label1' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to put together my first tkinter application, showing values recieved from Arduino serial port, I successfully managed to make console application, but I'm novice in GUI.

raw0 is string with 'NR'
raw 1 - 4 are int compatible values
raw5 is string 'EOR'

here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial
Arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB3', '115200', timeout=1)
print('Connection is working')

value1 = 0
value2 = 0
value3 = 0
value4 = 0

class App:

    def readdata(self):
        Arduino.write(bytes('n', 'utf-8'))
        for x in range(0, 6):
         globals()['raw%s' % x] = Arduino.readline().decode().strip()
        self.value1 = int(raw1)
        self.value2 = int(raw2)
        self.value3 = int(raw3)
        self.value4 = int(raw4)
        App.changelabels(self.mainframe)

    def changelabels(self):
        label1.config(text=self.value1.get())

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # build ui
        self.appwindow = tk.Tk() if master is None else tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.appwindow.configure(height=240, width=320)
        self.appwindow.minsize(320, 240)
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.appwindow)
        self.mainframe.configure(height=240, width=320)
        label1 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.value1 = tk.IntVar()
        label1.configure(textvariable=self.value1)
        label1.grid(column=1, row=0)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.value2 = tk.IntVar()
        label2.configure(textvariable=self.value2)
        label2.grid(column=1, row=1)
        label3 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.value3 = tk.IntVar()
        label3.configure(textvariable=self.value3)
        label3.grid(column=1, row=2)
        label4 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.value4 = tk.IntVar()
        label4.configure(textvariable=self.value4)
        label4.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.text1 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.text1.configure(text='Value1: ')
        self.text1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.text2 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.text2.configure(text='Value2: ')
        self.text2.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.text3 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.text3.configure(text='Value3: ')
        self.text3.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.text4 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)
        self.text4.configure(text='Value4:  ')
        self.text4.grid(column=0, row=3)
        progressbar1 = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe)
        progressbar1.configure(orient="horizontal")
        progressbar1.grid(column=2, row=0)
        progressbar2 = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe)
        progressbar2.configure(orient="horizontal")
        progressbar2.grid(column=2, row=1)
        progressbar3 = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe)
        progressbar3.configure(orient="horizontal")
        progressbar3.grid(column=2, row=2)
        progressbar4 = ttk.Progressbar(self.mainframe)
        progressbar4.configure(orient="horizontal")
        progressbar4.grid(column=2, row=3)
        self.refresh = ttk.Button(self.mainframe)
        self.refresh.configure(text='Refresh')
        self.refresh.configure(command=self.readdata)
        self.refresh.grid(column=1, row=4)
        self.mainframe.pack(side="top")

        # Main widget
        self.mainwindow = self.appwindow

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

I'm trying to update labels (label1-4) with variables stored in value1-4, but I'm unable to do so, mostly because I don't know how to approach labels correctly.
I've tried various ways how to approach this, but I've failed every time. Is anybody willing to kick me into right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `label1 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)` to `self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.mainframe)` and similarly prefix all references to `label1` with `self` everywhere else it's used. That way, all methods that are members of your `App` class (and have access to `self`) will have access to `self.label1`

Comment: It pushed me into right direction, also I've messed up "update label", correct form is         self.value1.set(int(raw1))